# __getattr__ equivalent for methods

Tags: python, object, methods, getattr

When an attribute is not found `object.__getattr__` is called. Is there an equivalent way to intercept undefined methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Methods are attributes too. `__getattr__` works the same for them:

```
class A(object):

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    print attr
```

Then try:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.thing
thing
>>> a.thing()
thing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 12):

There is no difference. A method is also an attribute. (If you want the method to have an implicit "self" argument, though, you'll have to do some more work to "bind" the method).

Comment: Second that, everything is an object, no matter if it's `int`, `str` or `function`.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't return anything.

```
class A(object):

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return attr
```

should work