# Python add methods of objects to containing list

Tags: python, list, object, containers, metaclass

I have a list containing objects of same class. now I want to make that list a container class that relates to all methods of the objects it contains as you can see in my example below. But since I have a lot of methods, I don't want to explicitly write them down in the containing container-class like this again:

module fe.py

```
class foo:

    def __init__(self,weight,age):
        self.weight = weight
        self.age = age

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.weight

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def multiply(self):
        return self.weight*self.age


class foo_list(list):

    def __init__(self,foo_tuple):
        list.__init__(self,foo_tuple)

    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        return [getattr(x,name)() for x in self]
```

Now an execution example:

```
import fe

u=fe.foo_list((fe.foo(1,2),fe.foo(3,4)))
u.multiply
[2, 12]
u.multiply()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

But this way the method-attribute got related to the result. but I want it to be a method to call just like in the contained objects

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your question or problem is, please clarify.

Comment: did it become clearer now?

Comment: Meta classes are unnecessary per se. How about simply implementing `__getattr__` to intercept undefined method calls?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855062/476

Comment: @deceze I think the OP has clarified the question enough for it to be re-opened. It's clear enough to me at least.

Comment: thanks to the hint about __getattribute__ I could create the container class like I wanted. the attribute now gives the result but is not callable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __getattribute__(self,name):
    return [getattr(x,name)() for x in self]
```

`__getattribute__` returns a list, which means just `u.multiply` is a list; which you're then trying to call. If you want this magic attribute to pose as a method, then `__getattribute__` will need to return a callable function:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    def f():
        return [getattr(x, name)() for x in self]
    return f
```

Comment: Note that there's an overhead incurred in redefining the function every time you make a call, which adds up if you intend to call these dynamic methods a lot, in which case it may be worth using a metaclass to generate the dynamic methods once during startup. Here's a demo (originally written as an answer but is now a comment since the question is closed): https://ideone.com/gL6at2